# Angular 2 / Observable code pattern for tracking process state

Tags: angular, firebase

I inherited a web solution using Angular 2 CLI and Firebase, and I'm trying to clean up the code.  It's a simple game that's using this code to keep the users sync'ed.

This is the code on the users side to keep track of the game state...

```
  ngDoCheck(){
    if(this.subGame['game_state'] == 'question'){
      this.setAnswerStart();
    }else if(this.subGame['game_state'] == "answer"){
      this.updateGame();
    }else if(this.subGame['game_state'] == 'leaderboard'){

      this.startTime = null;
      console.log("Question timer was reset to ZERO");
    }
  }
```

The subGame object is a subscription to the Firebase realtime DB, and the game is setting the game_state property to keep all users in sync.

The game walks through a quiz process like this:

1. Question: Show a question
2. Answer: Show the Answer
3. Leaderboard: Show
   Scores
4. [REPEAT]

The problem is since it's using the ngDoCheck hook to track state it's firing these events anytime the game object changes.  The setAnswerStart method tracks the time when a user sees a question, but in this code it gets fired anytime any user submits a response to the DB...so its not a very accurate time reading.

I'm hoping someone here on SO can show me a coding pattern for tracking a state object like this, when a dev needs to track a step by step process like this.  It would be very helpful if I have a way to set a listener for when an event happens like "if(going from step1 to step2)"

Answer (score 0):

yes you can using BeheviorSubject, or another EventEmitter, for example :

```
state = 'waiting';
checkState: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject(this.state);
```

then when when your user submit a question, simply do a `this.checkState.next('submitted')` after checking the form.

Then in your ngOnInit() subscribe to the state :

```
this.checkState.subscribe((state) => 
   {
     this.state = state;
   });
```